# Zeros of a function defined as a sum of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, power-series

I am having a problem concerning the zero set of the function defined as :
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sin \left ( \frac{x}{n} \right ).
$$
The question is to determine whether f has finitely many zeros or not on the real line $\mathbb{R}$. So far, it is easy to see that $f$ is entire (since the series defining $f$ converges uniformly on compact sets). Moreover, if you construct the representative curve of $f$, one can note that this curve seems to oscillate around a fixed value. More precisely, it is possible to check that :
$$
\lim_{p\to 0^+} p\int_0 ^{+\infty} f(t)e^{-pt}dt=\frac{\pi}{2}.
$$
The problem concerns now the amplitude of this oscillation. Is it strong enough to allow the appearance of infinitely many zeros? One can note that, if you modify the function slightly, for instance by considering the function $g_{\alpha} : x\longmapsto \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n^{1+\alpha}} \sin \left ( \frac{x}{n} \right )$, one can prove that $g_{\alpha}$ has infinitely many zeros if $\alpha>0$ (because $g_{\alpha}$ is almost periodic and odd) and finitely many zeros if $\alpha<0$ (because one can verify that $\lim_{x\to +\infty} g_{\alpha}(x)=+\infty$).

So, if you have got any suggestions or comments, thank you very much in advance...